# Mono trusts everyone except Google

Tags: c#, ssl, mono

I am working on an app that uses Google's services over SSL. However, when trying to connect I get the following exception.

```
System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in /build/mono/src/mono-4.6.1/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:430
```

I am running Mono version 4.6.1 on Arch Linux. Chrome and Firefox have no problem connecting to google.com over https.

I have followed the [steps here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/) to make sure the Mono's certificate store is in sync with my system's certificate store. I made sure that `ca-certificates` was installed and then I ran both `cert-sync /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and `mozroots --import`. I then tried using the `tlstest.exe` tool to test SSL connections to various websites. It succeeds in connecting to every site I could think of except google.com. This includes github.com, arstechnica.com, stackoverflow.com, nuget.org.

Here is what happens with Google.

```
$ mono tlstest.exe https://google.com

https://google.com
[Subject]
  CN=*.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=Google Internet Authority G2, O=Google Inc, C=US

[Not Before]
  2/1/2017 5:47:18 AM

[Not After]
  4/26/2017 6:21:00 AM

[Thumbprint]
  B2F9FF2ECD53E370B4401F00AFB7CC44F407A8CA


    Valid From:  2/1/2017 5:47:18 AM
    Valid Until: 4/26/2017 6:21:00 AM

Error #-2146762486: CERT_E_CHAINING 0x800B010A
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Same problem on my machine today. Any solution availble?

Comment: This is one of those problems that just went away after a while. You could try updating Mono and see if that makes a difference. They changed how TLS certificates work in recent versions.